# GNU-C-preprocessing FORTRAN source to change array indices causes recursion whilst expanding macro

Tags: preprocessor, gfortran, c-preprocessor, intel-fortran, preprocessor-directive

I am parallelizing an existing FORTRAN application. I don't want to directly change parts of its code   so I am using preprocessor directives to accomplish my goal. This way I am able to maintain the readability of the code and I won't induce errors in parts of the code that have already been tested. However, when I try to preprocess my source with the GNU C preprocessor I get the following error message (**gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)**):

```
test.f:9:0: error: detected recursion whilst expanding macro "ARR""
```

This simple test program demonstrates my problem:

```
      PROGRAM TEST

        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER I,OFFSET,ARR(10)

#define ARR(I) ARR(OFFSET+I)

        DO I=1,10
          ARR(I)=I
        END DO

#undef ARR(I)

      END PROGRAM TEST
```

This is the commandline output:

```
    testing$ gfortran -cpp -E test.f
# 1 "test.f"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "test.f"
      PROGRAM TEST
```

[...]

```
test.f:9:0: error: detected recursion whilst expanding macro "ARR"
        DO I=1,10
          ARR(OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+OFFSET+I)=I
        END DO
```

[...]

```
      END PROGRAM TEST
```

This site provides some information on the preprocessor I am using:

http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/cpp.html#SEC10

As it seems I am using a function-like macro with macro arguments.

**Why is the preprocessor detecting a recursion?** [EDIT] - Maybe because I use the same name for Makro and Identifier?
**Why isn't the preprocessor capable of interpreting upper case directives (#DEFINE instead of #define)?** - I am asking, because I haven't had this problem with the ifort preprocessor.

BTW: I am able to preprocess the **original** code either using the ifort preprocessor -fpp, or by changing the source in the following way:

```
      PROGRAM TEST

        IMPLICIT NONE
        INTEGER I,OFFSET,ARR(10)

#define ARR_T(I) ARR(OFFSET+I)

        DO I=1,10
          ARR_T(I)=I
        END DO

#undef ARR_T(I)

      END PROGRAM TEST
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why is the preprocessor detecting a recursion? [EDIT] - Maybe because I use the same name for Makro and Identifier?**

The preprocessor is detecting recursion because your macro name and array name are the same.

**Why isn't the preprocessor capable of interpreting upper case directives (#DEFINE instead of #define)? - I am asking, because I haven't had this problem with the ifort preprocessor.**

When using gfortran, you are using a C preprocessor.  #DEFINE is not a recognized preprocessor directive in C.  No idea about ifort.  I thought in ifort you had to prefix macros with !$MS or !$DEC.

Your change to the program to get it to work for ifort will also work for gfortran.

Comment: ifort uses their own variant of cpp called fpp. It apparently accepts capital letters.

Comment: @cup Thank you for your confirmation. I am afraid I will have to edit my post just for clarification. I didn't have to modify my program **at all** to compile it using gfortran, that's what got me wondering about gfortran.  

Indeed !MS$ and !DEC$ can be used for the same purpose with the ifort **compiler**, since they are compiler directives:  

http://nf.nci.org.au/facilities/software/Compilers/Intel8/doc/f_ug1/ug1_dir_options.htm  

However the ifort **preprocessor** fpp uses c/c++-style directives.  

!$ is the sentinel for compilation with openmp ;-)